# Convert bytes32 to ordered bytes2, bytes4, etc

Tags: solidity, bytes, bytes32

For example, 
I need to slice my bytes32 variable to chunks, and put result into 5 variables, saving the order, `bytes2`, `bytes2`, `bytes2`, `bytes2`, `bytes8`, `bytes1` (aka `byte`), the order should be saved and I don't really care about the rest of bytes.

Is solidity has some tools for that? Or it is only possible with bit operations.

I found some difficulties working with this low-level types.

UPDATE: 
So I did prepare this function which parses `numBytes` bytes from `source` starting from `start` byte.

```
function bytesChunck(bytes32 source, uint start, uint numBytes) constant returns(uint _result){
            uint counter = 0;
            uint result;

            for(uint i = 0; i < numBytes; i++) {
                result += uint8(source[start + i]);
            }
            return result;
            // 
    }
```

then I just convert result to needed bytes, like `bytes8(result)`. But it seems to be overflowed, since if I have like 8 bytes it first bytes always zeros. Any ideas? :)

Thank you.

Comment: This is sort of confusing. When you say "saving the order", do you mean keep the bytes in the original order or do you mean sort them? Also, can you give us 5 vars that add up to 32 bytes so we can know what you want? Lastly, first thought is it would be best, if possible, to chop up the large bytes into these five chunks before interacting with the contract. Is it really necessarily to perform this step inside the smart contract? Controlling gas cost tends toward avoiding this sort of thing in Solidity.

Comment: @RobHitchens thx for the comment. I would like to save the original order (not sort again). I will add samples a bit later .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough. When you want to split 32 bytes into 5 variables that have a total length of `2+2+2+2+8+1 = 17` you should specify what bytes you want to be chunked (bytes from left or bytes from right).

I wrote an example that solves your problem as far as I could understand it. Comment the answer - explain what you exactly need, and I'll change the code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract BytesChunkTest
{
    bytes32 constant public test_source=0x000000000000000000ff11223344556677889900aabbccddeeff;

    bytes32 constant mask1 = 0xff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    bytes32 constant mask2 = 0xffff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    bytes32 constant mask8 = 0xffffffffffffffff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    uint    constant main_shift=15;

    function sourceToChunk(bytes32 source) constant
    returns
        (
            bytes2 r1_2,
            bytes2 r2_2,
            bytes2 r3_2,
            bytes2 r4_2,
            bytes8 r5_8,
            bytes1 r6_1
        )
    {

        r1_2 = bytes2(source<<(main_shift*8)&mask2);
        r2_2 = bytes2((source<<(main_shift+2)*8)&mask2);
        r3_2 = bytes2((source<<(main_shift+4)*8)&mask2);
        r4_2 = bytes2((source<<(main_shift+6)*8)&mask2);
        r5_8 = bytes8((source<<(main_shift+8)*8)&mask8);
        r6_1 = bytes1((source<<(main_shift+16)*8)&mask1);
    }


    function test() constant
    returns
        (
            bytes2,
            bytes2,
            bytes2,
            bytes2,
            bytes8,
            bytes1
        )
    {
        return sourceToChunk(test_source);
    }
}
```